# Merge or update multidimensional associative array using php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array

I have two arrays.

```
$all_labels = [
    'data'=> [
        ['label'=> NULL],
        ['label'=> "C1.SNM"],
        ['label'=> "C1.SSM"],
        ['label'=> "C1.TAM"],
        ['label'=> "C1.TIM"],
        ['label'=> "C1.TNM"],
        ['label'=> "C1.TOM"]
    ]
];

$non_complianceData3 = [
    'data'=> [
        ['label'=> "C1.TAM", 'value'=> "1674"],
        ['label'=> "C1.TOM", 'value'=> "574"]
    ]
];
```

I need the first array to act as the base, i.e. this returns all the labels available from the db. I then need to update the base by using the `$non_complianceData3` array data values with the matching labels, in this case the base `"C1.TAM"` needs to be updated with `'value'=> "1674"`, and the `"C1.TOM"` with `'value'=> "574"`.

How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the labels in `$all_labels` are distinct, it can be done this way:

```
// reindex $all_labels['data'] by label
$all_labels['data'] = array_column($all_labels['data'], null, 'label');

// assign the values from $non_complianceData3['data'] to the new keys
foreach ($non_complianceData3['data'] as $item) {
    $all_labels['data'][$item['label']] = $item;
}
```

If the labels in `$all_labels` are not distinct, it can be done like this:

```
// loop over the items in $non_complianceData3['data']
foreach ($non_complianceData3['data'] as $item) {

    // find all of the matching labels in $all_labels['data'] and replace
    // them with the corresponding $non_complianceData3['data'] items
    foreach ($all_labels['data'] as $key => $value) {
        if ($item['label'] == $value['label']) {
            $all_labels['data'][$key] = $item;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, quick response, I have spent hours researching and trying to work this out!! This is my first question here, what a service, you just saved my butt big time - I am in the office working over the weekend to meet a deadline next week. Thank you very much!!

Comment: Happy to help. Good luck with your deadline!